# VBA, If value Like

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column(x) and trying to do a If and like in another column(d). Getting a range error on the selection autofill part.

```
Dim src As Range
Set src = Worksheets("File").Range("2:17783")


    If (Range("x2").Value Like "*ProductType:'FXD';*") Then
                         Range("D2").Value = "FXD"
            ElseIf (Range("x2").Value Like "*;ProductSubType:'SWLEG'*") Then
                         Range("D2").Value = "XSW" 
            End If 

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=src.Columns("D")
```

Comment: Instr could work here too I believe.

Comment: Where does `17783` come from? What column dictates the extent of the values in column D... column X perhaps?

Comment: its column d last row.

Comment: So column D is already populated with values to the full extent that you want to repopulate it?

Comment: Don't leave orphaned cell references like `Range("x2")` without a defined parent.

Comment: no, i want to to the it formula in column D, using col x as the condition

Comment: @Jeeped , i have removed it.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of doing autofill just set the value at once.

Also do not forget to provide the sheet parent to all your range objects:

```
Dim src As Range
Set src = Worksheets("File").Range("2:17783")


If (Worksheets("File").Range("x2").Value Like "*ProductType:'FXD';*") Then
    Worksheets("File").Range("D2:D17783").Value = "FXD"
ElseIf (Worksheets("File").Range("x2").Value Like "*;ProductSubType:'SWLEG'*") Then
    Worksheets("File").Range("D2:D17783").Value = "XSW" 
End If
```

Comment: column D is not being populated with anything

Comment: Remember to tag Scott using @ if you want more replies from him.

Comment: put a msgbox inside each of the ifs to ensure that the value is being found.  @excelguy.  I would bet you are not finding either.

Comment: what do you mean msgbox?

Comment: Put `msgbox "Here 1"` after the `If .. Then` line and `msgbox "Here 2"` after the `ElseIf .. Then` line.  if neither msgbox appears then you need to look to the values you are testing to ensure there are no typos.

Answer (score 2):

Try using column X to set the extents of the values to fill in column D.

```
with worksheets("file")
    select case true
        case .cells(2, "X").value2 like "*ProductType:'FXD';*"
            .range(.cells(2, "D"), .cells(.cells(.rows.count, "X").end(xlup).row, "D")) = "FXD"
        case .cells(2, "X").value2 like "*;ProductSubType:'SWLEG'*"
            .range(.cells(2, "D"), .cells(.cells(.rows.count, "X").end(xlup).row, "D")) = "XSW"
        case else
            'do nothing
    end select
end with
```

Comment: column d still not getting any values

Answer (score 1):

Try changing 
`Selection.AutoFill Destination:=src.Columns("D")` to 
`Selection.AutoFill Destination:=src.Columns("D:D")`

This is going to drag that formula all the way down column D, which is what I assumed you're trying to do, however, it will literally go down to row 1048576, so unless you're trying to do that, change the second range to `D` & `whatevervaluehere`

Comment: i get a type mismatch on `Selection.AutoFill Destination:=src.Columns("D:D17783")`  , but damn my macro runs so slow now

Comment: Get rid of `Columns` and just do Worksheets("File").Range.("D:D17783"). And yes, autofilling formulas will probably slow down your macro drastically if calculations is on. Maybe turn it off before running?

Comment: @excelguy I'd also suggest looking into Scott's solution below - might be more feasible.